# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: java, android, sqlite

````
**java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ardaak.nottutma/com.ardaak.nottutma.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLENot": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: CREATE TABLENot(Counter INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, id INT, baslik TEXT, aciklama TEXT, silinmisTEXT)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLENot": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: CREATE TABLENot(Counter INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, id INT, baslik TEXT, aciklama TEXT, silinmisTEXT)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1045)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:652)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:590)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:61)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:33)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1919)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1841)
at com.ardaak.nottutma.SQLite.onCreate(SQLite.java:68)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:411)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:340)
# ```at com.ardaak.nottutma.SQLite.populateNotListArray(SQLite.java:101)
at com.ardaak.nottutma.MainActivity.VeritabanindanMemorye(MainActivity.java:45)
at com.ardaak.nottutma.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
2022-12-19 03:24:15.800 9217-9217/com.ardaak.nottutma I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 9217 SIG: 9**
````

## This is MainActivity.java**

```
package com.ardaak.nottutma;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private ListView notListview;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initWidgets();
        VeritabanindanMemorye();
        setNotUyarlama();
    }

    private void setNotUyarlama()
    {
        NotUyarlama notUyarlama = new NotUyarlama(getApplicationContext(),Not.notArrayList);
        notListview.setAdapter(notUyarlama);
    }

    private void initWidgets()
    {
        notListview = findViewById(R.id.lstNotlarim);
    }

    public void YeniNot(View view)
    {
        Intent YeniNotIntent = new Intent(this,NotDuzenleme.class);
        startActivity(YeniNotIntent);
    }
    public void VeritabanindanMemorye()
    {
        SQLite sqLite = SQLite.instanceOfDatabase(this);
        sqLite.populateNotListArray();
    }
}
```

## This is MainActivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/KoyuYesil"
        android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?actionBarTheme">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtNotlarim"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="NOTLARIM"
            android:textColor="@color/Gri"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnEkle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:onClick="YeniNot"
            android:text="Ekle +"
            android:textColor="@color/Sari" />


    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lstNotlarim"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:divider="@color/teal_700"
        android:dividerHeight="4dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**NotDuzenleme class same again its NoteDetailActivity**

```
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    
    public class NotDuzenleme extends AppCompatActivity
    {
        private EditText baslikEditText,aciklamaEditText;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_not_duzenleme);
            initWidgets();
        }
    
        private void initWidgets()
        {
            baslikEditText = findViewById(R.id.editBaslik);
            aciklamaEditText = findViewById(R.id.editNot);
        }
    
        public void KaydetNot(View view)
        {
            SQLite sqLite = SQLite.instanceOfDatabase(this);
            String baslik = String.valueOf(baslikEditText.getText());
            String aciklama = String.valueOf(aciklamaEditText.getText());
    
            int id = Not.notArrayList.size();
            Not yeniNot = new Not(id,baslik,aciklama);
            Not.notArrayList.add(yeniNot);
            sqLite.DatabaseNotEkle(yeniNot);
            finish();
        }
    }

**This is the NotUyarlama class NoteAdapter  class in his video**

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
    
    import org.w3c.dom.Text;
    
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    
    public class NotUyarlama extends ArrayAdapter<Not>
    {
        public NotUyarlama(Context context, List<Not> nots)
        {
            super(context, 0, nots);
    
        }
    
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent)
        {
            Not not = getItem(position);
            if(convertView == null)
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.not_hucreleri,parent,false);
    
            TextView baslik = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtBaslik);
            TextView aciklama = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtAciklama);
    
            baslik.setText(not.getBaslik());
            aciklama.setText(not.getAciklama());
    
    
            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

**Note class**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

public class Not {

    public static ArrayList<Not> notArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    private int id;
    private String baslik;
    private String aciklama;
    private Date silinmis;

    public Not(int id, String baslik, String aciklama, Date silinmis) {
        this.id = id;
        this.baslik = baslik;
        this.aciklama = aciklama;
        this.silinmis = silinmis;
    }

    public Not(int id, String baslik, String aciklama) {
        this.id = id;
        this.baslik = baslik;
        this.aciklama = aciklama;
        silinmis =null;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getBaslik() {
        return baslik;
    }

    public void setBaslik(String baslik) {
        this.baslik = baslik;
    }

    public String getAciklama() {
        return aciklama;
    }

    public void setAciklama(String aciklama) {
        this.aciklama = aciklama;
    }

    public Date getSilinmis() {
        return silinmis;
    }

    public void setSilinmis(Date silinmis) {
        this.silinmis = silinmis;
    }
}
```

**The SQLite class**

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


public class SQLite extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    private static SQLite sqLite;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "NotDB";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "NotList";
    private static final String COUNTER = "Counter";

    private static final String ID_FIELD = "id";
    private static final String BASLIK_FIELD = "baslik";
    private static final String ACIKLAMA_FIELD = "aciklama";
    private static final String SILINMIS_FIELD = "silinmis";

    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    private static final DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");


    public SQLite(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public static SQLite instanceOfDatabase(Context context)
    {
        if(sqLite == null)
            sqLite = new SQLite(context);


        return sqLite;
    }




    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase)
    {
        StringBuilder sql;
        sql = new StringBuilder()
                .append("CREATE TABLE")
                .append(TABLE_NAME)
                .append("(")
                .append(COUNTER)
                .append(" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, ")
                .append(ID_FIELD)
                .append(" INT ")
                .append(BASLIK_FIELD)
                .append(" TEXT, ")
                .append(ACIKLAMA_FIELD)
                .append(" TEXT, ")
                .append(SILINMIS_FIELD)
                .append("TEXT)");
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(sql.toString());

    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
//        switch (oldVersion)
//        {
//            case 1:
//               sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ADD COLUMN " + NEW_COLUMN + " TEXT");
//            case 2:
//                sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ADD COLUMN " + NEW_COLUMN + " TEXT");
//        }
    }
    public void DatabaseNotEkle(Not not)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(ID_FIELD,not.getId());
        contentValues.put(BASLIK_FIELD,not.getBaslik());
        contentValues.put(ACIKLAMA_FIELD,not.getAciklama());
        contentValues.put(SILINMIS_FIELD, getStringFromDate(not.getSilinmis()));
        
        sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);


    }

        public void populateNotListArray()
        {
            SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();


         try  (Cursor result = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null))
         {
             if(result.getCount() != 0)
             {
                 while(result.moveToNext())
                 {
                     int id = result.getInt(1);
                     String baslik=result.getString(2);
                     String aciklama=result.getString(3);
                     String silinmisString=result.getString(4);
                     Date silinmis = getDateFromString(silinmisString);
                     Not not = new Not(id,baslik,aciklama,silinmis);
                     Not.notArrayList.add(not);
                 }
             }
         }
        }

    private void NotGuncelle (Not not)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(ID_FIELD,not.getId());
        contentValues.put(BASLIK_FIELD,not.getBaslik());
        contentValues.put(ACIKLAMA_FIELD,not.getAciklama());
        contentValues.put(SILINMIS_FIELD,getStringFromDate(not.getSilinmis()));

        sqLiteDatabase.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, ID_FIELD + " =? ",new String[]{String.valueOf(not.getId())});


    }

    private String getStringFromDate(Date date)
    {
        if(date == null)
            return null;
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }
    private Date getDateFromString(String string)
    {
        try{
            return dateFormat.parse(string);
        }
        catch (ParseException | NullPointerException e)
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4k1ZMpO9Zn0&t=732s
I'm trying to do this app by doing everything he does in a video i made it to 14:12 then he tests the save data to database i guess he runs the device but when I try to run the device I had problems and my app keeps stopping I cant run it I'm using SQLite like he does and its on android studio.

Comment: `CREATE TABLENot(` - looks like you missed a space after `TABLE`.

Comment: can you provide sqlite database code for more information

Comment: Did you read the error message you posted? Do you understand what it said?

Comment: i have added all the classes along with the SQLite class too from minute 8 to 14.25 . @ianhanniballake i didnt found the problem but problem is somewhere there because it was running before i did the class

Comment: @TylerV Not really :/ cause of that i cant fix it sorry im very bad at this but i need this for my project

Comment: Do you guys need the xmls too ? let me know if you do

Comment: use `(Counter INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, id INT, baslik TEXT, aciklama TEXT, silinmis TEXT)` instead of `(Counter INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, id INT, baslik TEXT, aciklama TEXT, silinmisTEXT)`  here you had mistake `silinmisTEXT` just leave space between them `silinmis TEXT`

Comment: @UrvishShiroya 
 .append("TEXT)"); i did made an space and made .append(" TEXT)");
but still same error 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ardaak.nottutma/com.ardaak.nottutma.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLENotList": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: CREATE TABLENotList(Counter INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, id INT baslik TEXT, aciklama TEXT, silinmis TEXT)

Comment: The error message (`SQLiteException: near "TABLENot": syntax error`) tells you what the problem is (`TABLENot` is not valid SQL syntax - you are likely missing a space in there) and tells you the full SQL command it found that error in. The only relevant code here is the part you use to generate that particular SQL command... Print out your SQL string and make sure it is valid.

Comment: @TylerV i dont know how to print it ive searched it but cant found it i made many many space problems watched the video from the start but it still not opening how can i print it ?


'java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ardaak.nottutma/com.ardaak.nottutma.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Not": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE Not (Counter INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, id INT baslik TEXT, aciklama TEXT, silinmis TEXT)'

Comment: The string you create with `sql = new StringBuilder()` is invalid SQL - that is where you are missing spaces. You can print a string to the logcat with `System.out.println("SQL string is " + sql.toString())` after you build it then look in the logcat tab to see the value of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one issue with your code.

You are missing a space in SQL when creating a table. So let's assume you rename the table to NotEntity and then the code would look something like this:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


public class SQLite extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    private static SQLite sqLite;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "NotDB";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "NotList";
    private static final String COUNTER = "Counter";

    private static final String ID_FIELD = "id";
    private static final String BASLIK_FIELD = "baslik";
    private static final String ACIKLAMA_FIELD = "aciklama";
    private static final String SILINMIS_FIELD = "silinmis";

    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    private static final DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");


    public SQLite(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public static SQLite instanceOfDatabase(Context context)
    {
        if(sqLite == null)
            sqLite = new SQLite(context);


        return sqLite;
    }




    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase)
    {
        StringBuilder sql;
        sql = new StringBuilder()
                .append("CREATE TABLE ")
                .append(TABLE_NAME)
                .append(" (")
                .append(COUNTER)
                .append(" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, ")
                .append(ID_FIELD)
                .append(" INT ")
                .append(BASLIK_FIELD)
                .append(" TEXT, ")
                .append(ACIKLAMA_FIELD)
                .append(" TEXT, ")
                .append(SILINMIS_FIELD)
                .append("TEXT)");
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(sql.toString());

    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
//        switch (oldVersion)
//        {
//            case 1:
//               sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ADD COLUMN " + NEW_COLUMN + " TEXT");
//            case 2:
//                sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ADD COLUMN " + NEW_COLUMN + " TEXT");
//        }
    }
    public void DatabaseNotEkle(Not not)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(ID_FIELD,not.getId());
        contentValues.put(BASLIK_FIELD,not.getBaslik());
        contentValues.put(ACIKLAMA_FIELD,not.getAciklama());
        contentValues.put(SILINMIS_FIELD, getStringFromDate(not.getSilinmis()));
        
        sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);


    }

        public void populateNotListArray()
        {
            SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();


         try  (Cursor result = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null))
         {
             if(result.getCount() != 0)
             {
                 while(result.moveToNext())
                 {
                     int id = result.getInt(1);
                     String baslik=result.getString(2);
                     String aciklama=result.getString(3);
                     String silinmisString=result.getString(4);
                     Date silinmis = getDateFromString(silinmisString);
                     Not not = new Not(id,baslik,aciklama,silinmis);
                     Not.notArrayList.add(not);
                 }
             }
         }
        }

    private void NotGuncelle (Not not)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(ID_FIELD,not.getId());
        contentValues.put(BASLIK_FIELD,not.getBaslik());
        contentValues.put(ACIKLAMA_FIELD,not.getAciklama());
        contentValues.put(SILINMIS_FIELD,getStringFromDate(not.getSilinmis()));

        sqLiteDatabase.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, ID_FIELD + " =? ",new String[]{String.valueOf(not.getId())});


    }

    private String getStringFromDate(Date date)
    {
        if(date == null)
            return null;
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }
    private Date getDateFromString(String string)
    {
        try{
            return dateFormat.parse(string);
        }
        catch (ParseException | NullPointerException e)
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Wow it really does worked but i dont know what u changed ? ive checked like 3 4 times didnt found a difference ur code works ! but i have still one problem when i add the notes it doesnt come until i ''press apply changes and restart activity'' button 
then when i close the app and open it the note that i added is gone is it because of my database ? how can i find it

Comment: I added a space in the sql table creation query. And for that data observing, well, you need to observe changes in the database. Otherwise it's not possible. By the way, I'd recommend looking into Room library. If you are satisfied with the answer, please mark it as accepted